# Change background of SVG image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am trying to change the background image of my svg when a user selects a different images, the images are put into an array and passed into the react component and then updates the image with the background image, this will add the first image but it add the second image, presumably the code i'm using to target `#img2` in the svg is incorrect or I have incorrect code in the svg to use for multiple background images

`svg.find('image').attr("href", this.props.pattern[0]);` this works
`svg.find('pattern').find('#img2').find('image').attr("href", this.props.pattern[1]);` this does not work

How can I target `fill="url(#img2)` with my second image in the array?

**array of data**

```
{ https://example.com/image1},
{ https://example.com/image2}
```

**react component**

```
   class InlineSVG extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      image: '',
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadSVG();
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    prevProps.src !== this.props.src && this.loadSVG()
    if (this.state.image && prevProps.pattern !== this.props.pattern) {
      this.updateColors()
    }
  }

  setImage = (image) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      image,
    });
  }

  loadSVG() {
      fetch(this.props.src)
        .then(
          response => {
            if (!response.ok) return Promise.reject(new Error('Server Error'));
            return response.text();
          }
        ).then(
          svg => this.setState({ image:  svg})
        )
  }

  updateColors() {
    const svg = $(this.state.image);
    if (svg) {
      svg.find('image').attr("href", this.props.pattern[0]);
      svg.find('pattern').find('#img2').find('image').attr("href", this.props.pattern[1]);


      this.setImage(svg.prop('outerHTML') || $('<div>').append($(svg).clone()).html());
    }

  }
```

**svg**

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
    <image id="bg" href="" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </pattern>
  <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
    <image id="bg" href="" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
<path id="cloth-color-2" fill="url(#img2)" d="M179.4,93l-2.6,5.1v0.1l2.7,5.8v0.1l-2.7,5.1v0.1l2.7,5.8v0.1l-2.7,5.2v0.1l2.7,5.7v0.1
    l-2.7,5.2v0.1l2.7,5.8v0.1l-2.7,5.2v0.1l2.7,5.7v0.1l-2.8,5.2v0.1l2.7,5.6c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.2H2.3c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2l2.7-5.6
    v-0.1l-2.7-5.2v-0.1l2.7-5.7v-0.1l-2.7-5.2v-0.1l2.7-5.8v-0.1l-2.7-5.2v-0.1l2.7-5.7v-0.1l-2.7-5.2v-0.1l2.7-5.8v-0.1l-2.7-5.1V104
    l2.7-5.8v-0.1L2.3,93c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2h176.9C179.4,92.9,179.4,93,179.4,93z"/>
<path id="cloth-color-1" fill="url(#img1)" d="M176.8,22.4l2.6-5.1c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.2H2.4c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2l2.6,5.1v0.1l-2.7,5.8
    v0.1l2.7,5.2v0.1l-2.7,5.7v0.1l2.7,5.2v0.1l-2.7,5.7v0.1l2.7,5.2v0.1l-2.7,5.8v0.1L4.9,67v0.1l-2.7,5.7v0.1l2.7,5.2v0.1l-2.5,5.3
    c0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2h176.6c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2l-2.5-5.3v-0.1l2.7-5.2v-0.1l-2.7-5.7V67l2.7-5.2v-0.1l-2.7-5.8v-0.1l2.7-5.2v-0.1
    l-2.7-5.7v-0.1l2.7-5.2v-0.1l-2.7-5.8v-0.1l2.7-5.1v-0.1l-2.7-5.8C176.8,22.5,176.8,22.5,176.8,22.4z"/>
```

Comment: Can you please add the render method to your question? and also, are you using JQuery?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about the usage of your Component? what is it that you want to achieve with it, does your component always render 2 svg's with background images? do you want to reuse the component so that it renders an svg with a background image and then you use this component twice in a different component?

Comment: I use  `<div  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.image}} />`, this works fine if selecting one background image, and usually I only need to set one but occasionally it will be an array of 2 images

Answer (score 0):

you can change background color with help CSS.

Frist inspect and find class/id/attribute of that inner component of svg element and then write css property for that.

Comment: yes that is what I have done, the first line `svg.find('image').attr("href", this.props.pattern[0]);` works but my second line doesn`t

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to update the svg image with 2 different backgrounds

```
svg.find('#img1').find('image').attr("href", this.props.pattern[0]);
svg.find('#img2').find('image').attr("href", this.props.pattern[1]);
```